# How to create specific wordpress Table

Tags: plugins, customization, table

How can I create such table in wordpress using plugin? Any hints to do it? [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a great number of ways to create such table. It is rather difficult to give an exact answer without knowing all the requirements and specifications. Here are some general level ideas that should get you started.

- First of all you'll probably want to create [a custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/) to host all the relevant code.
- Assuming the tabular data comes from posts (default '[post](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/#post)' post type or [a custom one](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/)), use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to retrieve the data.
- To get the categories above the table you can either use [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) or [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) (if [a custom taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/) is used).
- Once you have the post data, loop [the Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and render the table markup - [many ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array).

Within your loop you can, for example, use the following functions to retrieve the cell data from [the post objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/).

- Image - [the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)
- Title - [the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/)
- Hyperlink - [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/)
- Created - [the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/)
- Updated - [the_modified_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_date/)
- Views - [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) (if stored as [post meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/))

Finally, consider [localizing](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/) the table and add a dash of [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to make the table look fancy.

Happy coding!

*P.s. If you were looking for a plugin recommendation instead of a code solution, please note that recommedations are considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.*